# Android Edittext scroll horizontally

Tags: android

As You Can See In The Image The Text in the EditText name field moves vertically if screen finishes. I want this to move horizontally, Can anyone help me, please

[image: activty xml android]

The Code I am using in my activity XML is as follows:

```
   <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_name_signup"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            />
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you want exactly.

Comment: actually i want the text to increase vertically neither downwards (horizontally) as they are moving downwards if the screen layout finishes. you can see in the name section . i have posted an image

Comment: Check this android:singleLine=true OR  android:maxLines="1"

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated use android:maxLines for that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_name_signup"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

android:maxLines="1" even scroll vertically but it will show one line only. It will not scroll EditText horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing my case:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
```

The `textMultiLine` prevents horizontal scrolling, So can not use them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will be scroll horizontally and in single line.

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:singleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but it might help future viewers. Just add this to your `Edittext`

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
```

Answer (score 0):

For input that contains more than 1 line, try entering EditText into the HorizontalScrollView

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```